# php mysqli error mysql_fetch_row()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want make function that check whether specific data is in mydb in mysql. I wrote below function but I get error this line `$is_ok_array=mysql_fetch_row($is_ok);` Can Someone help me? Sorry my bad English :)

It says: `mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter.` I searched that error express that my sql doesn't work properly. But my sql query is working. Here is

```
$query_add ="INSERT INTO notes1 (id,name,size,url,thumbnail_url,delete_url,delete_type)    VALUES('$_SESSION[userid]','$file_name','$file_size','$file_url','$file_thumbnail_url','$delete_url','$delete_type')";
```

-- My Function

```
protected function is_same($file_name,$file_size,$file_url,$file_thumbnail_url,$delete_url1,$delete_type1) {

    $query_same = "Select * From notes1 WHERE id='$_SESSION[userid]' and name='$file_name' and size='$file_size' and url='$file_url' and thumbnail_url='$file_thumbnail_url' and      delete_url='$delete_url1' and delete_type='$delete_type1'" or die (mysql_error());
    $is_ok = mysqli_query($this->is_db_open,$query_same);   

    if($is_ok) {
        $is_ok_array = mysql_fetch_row($is_ok);
    } else { 
        echo "Wrong query";
    }

    if($this->is_db_open) {

        echo count($is_ok_array);

        if((count($is_ok_array))>0) { 
            return true;
        } else {    
            return false;
        }

    } else {
        echo "Db not open";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 problems with your code, the first is:

```
$is_ok= mysqli_query($this->is_db_open,$query_same);
```

Based on the fact that you're using it in an if statement later in the code and the naming, it seems like `$this->is_db_open` is a boolean indicating if you have a connection to the database or not, rather than the connection object returned from `mysqli_connect()`.

`mysqli_query()` expects the first parameter to either be the connection object, or the query if there is no second parameter. Either remove the `$this->is_db_open` parameter and it will default to the most recently opened database connection, or replace it with the actual connection object.

Your second problem is that you are running the query with `mysqli_query()` and returning the result with `mysql_fetch_row()`. You need to use `mysqli_fetch_row()` to match your query function.

Answer (score 1):

you are using a `mysqli_*` query

```
mysqli_query($this->is_db_open,$query_same);
     ^
```

but then using a `mysql_*` fetch

```
mysql_fetch_row($is_ok);
```

try using the `mysqli_` fetch_row

```
mysqli_fetch_row($is_ok);
     ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `mysqli_query` result with `mysql_` functions. Apparently, you want to use [`mysql_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Also, just in case, ensure that you've [connected to mysql](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You are using mysql_fetch_row() to fetch the results of a query.  However mysql_fetch_row() has been deprecated. Read this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

Please use mysqli_fetch_row() to get the results.